# Append key value to existing json using python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I am trying to append a value to existing JSON string using python, after that I have to load it into MongoDB

```
import xmltodict

from pymongo import Connection

s = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<to>aaa</to>
<from>bbb</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>This is the content</body>
</note>'

result = xmltodict.parse(s)

result.append({"cc":var1})

print result
```

But following error show :

```
AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

can you please help me to resolve this? I tried with different append options but facing some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OrderedDict* doesn't have the `append()` method (that is for lists), you need to use `update()` instead.

```
result.update({"cc":var1})
```